# Is it possible to set the selectedIndex of a combobox based on its value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, selectedindex

Is it possible to set the selectedIndex of a combobox based on its value, without having to iterate through the datasource?

I set the datasource like this:

```
caseDBTableAdapters.usersTableAdapter usersAdapter = new caseDBTableAdapters.usersTableAdapter();
            caseDB.usersDataTable users;
            users = usersAdapter.GetUsers();

            cbOwner.DisplayMember = "fullName";
            cbOwner.ValueMember = "userId";
            cbOwner.DataSource = users;
```

It seems less elegant to have to iterate through the table fx. by doing:

```
int counter = 0;
            foreach (caseDB.usersRow usersRow in users)
            {

                if (usersRow.userId == selectedUser)
                {

                    cbOwner.SelectedIndex = counter;

                }
                counter++;
            }
```

Comment: it would be easier to others to help you if you can provide some sample code.

Comment: @Rajesh - I've allready provided sample code, do you need more?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try assing

```
comboBox.SelectedValue = "value";
```

or

```
comboBox.SelectedItem = item;
```

After question edit:

Set SelectedValue to selectedUser:

```
cbOwner.SelectedValue = selectedUser;
```

Comment: I love the fact that you can do this

Answer (score 5):

When you use the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties, set `SelectedValue`.

Otherwise, set `SelectedItem`.

Comment: I seriously found it hard to believe this article was about the 15th on my Google search for "do you use selectedindex if you use datasource", when it seems to me such a common thing to come across! Thanks